# Why does GetCurrentRegistrations not return my open generic registration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly gets returned from a call to `GetCurrentRegistrations`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to determine whether a `Register` call might already have been called before. In that case, I would like to skip and continue. It is essential that the container does not get locked in the process!

For example:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register(typeof(IFoo), typeof(Foo), Lifestyle.Transient);
var currentRegistrations = container.GetCurrentRegistrations();
if (currentRegistrations.Any(r => producer.ServiceType == typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
{
    // skip
}
```

Above seems to work perfectly. However, when the types are open generic then the call to `GetCurrentRegistrations` does not return the registration:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CommandHandler<>), Lifestyle.Transient);
var currentRegistrations = container.GetCurrentRegistrations();
if (currentRegistrations.Any(r => producer.ServiceType == typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
{
    // currentRegistrations is empty, so we are not getting here :-(
}
```

Is there another way to determine this (without locking the container)?

Looking at the return type, wouldn't a better name be `GetCurrentInstanceProducers`? Come to think of it... (perhaps partly answering my own question now) could it be that the actual `InstanceProducers` are not yet available for open generic registrations?

Comment: Why do you need to check if the registration exists?

Comment: We have a package that needs to register its internal types. To do this we provide an extension method that can be called on the container. Normally the application will just reference the package and call the extension method.

Now we also have additional packages that depend on said package. Depending on the application, the extension method can now be called from different parts, so we want to prevent duplicate registration.

For our use-case it suffices to check on a concrete type, but as I was testing I found that the open generic didn't come back. Hence my question.

Comment: "wouldn't a better name be GetCurrentInstanceProducers". Yes, it would. This is some unfortunate legacy. The method existed before the existence of the InstanceProducer class, and at the time InstanceProducer was introduced, we decided to keep the breaking change minimal by keeping the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetCurrentRegistrations` can't return open-generic registrations, because an `InstanceProducer` only exists for a single closed-generic type. So one single open-generic registration can result in hundreds of `InstanceProducer` instances. Open generics in Simple Injector is done through unregistered type resolution, which means that the construct is similar to having event. In case a closed-generic type is resolved for which no explicit registration exists, Simple Injector checks to see whether there is a matching open-generic registration. Only in the last moment, the `InstanceProducer` is created.

So you can't use `GetCurrentRegistrations` to do the job. In your case, you're probably better of by setting a flag in the container to allow skipping the registration. For instance:

```cs
private static readonly object key = new object();

public static void MyExtensionMethod(this Container container)
{

    if (container.ContainerScope.GetItem(key) is null)
    {
        // do registrations here
        container.ContainerScope.SetItem(key, new object());
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. This feels like a much better approach. I was not aware of the fact that one could use the `ContainerScope` to add custom entries.

Comment: Both the Container and a Scope give access to a dictionary which lives outside the context of the resolve pipeline (meaning: it's just a bad of data, unused by Simple Injector). It allows you to link some custom state either with the container or a scope.